# Is there a way to countdown 4 weeks (week by week) based on a date? Php/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, css, date, datetime

I need some help here guys, is there a way to countdown 4weeks in a month based on a **date**? And tell the user based on that **date** that has 4weeks remaning? and after another week say to him that has "3weeks" and so on..
If the user reaches the **date**  then tell him for example (your account will be ended if you not pay). And when i setting up another date, the countdown starts again..week by week until his end date. Thanks

Comment: yes, there's a way. what've you tried until now? can you do some example with the expected output?

Comment: honestly.. I do not know where to start..some advice/script or something that will help.. and it will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `datediff`:

```
set @var := date '2016-04-30';
select
    case    when (@remaining := datediff(@var, curdate())) > 4 * 7 then ''
            when @remaining > 3 * 7 then '4 weeks remaining'
            when @remaining > 2 * 7 then '3 weeks remaining'
            when @remaining > 1 * 7 then '2 weeks remaining'
            when @remaining > 0 * 7 then '1 weeks remaining'
            else 'time is up'
    end  as `Remaining reminder`;
```

### Output:

```
mysql> set @var := date '2016-04-30';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select
    ->     case    when (@remaining := datediff(@var, curdate())) > 4 * 7 then ''
    ->             when @remaining > 3 * 7 then '4 weeks remaining'
    ->             when @remaining > 2 * 7 then '3 weeks remaining'
    ->             when @remaining > 1 * 7 then '2 weeks remaining'
    ->             when @remaining > 0 * 7 then '1 weeks remaining'
    ->             else 'time is up'
    ->     end  as `Remaining reminder`;
+--------------------+
| Remaining reminder |
+--------------------+
| 4 weeks remaining  |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### P.S.

Update @var to your target `date`.

Comment: Ok Dylan, can u tell me how to use this in php ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## PHP Solution

Here is another simple solution. provided the expire date (date the account ended) and current date.

```
function get_weeks_remaining($date, $expire_date){
    $difference = strtotime($expire) - strtotime($date);
    return floor($difference / 604800);
}
```

Here is the solution [ideaone](https://ideone.com/F48q2B)

---

*PS: 604800 is seconds in 7 days / 1 week*

Comment: And how can i use-it in php, and echo the users with weeks remaining?

Comment: Please view the ideaone link in reference. You can echo it like this `echo get_weeks_remaining([your_current_date], [your_expire_date])`

Comment: Is ok i just add $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()); , for curent date :)

Comment: You don't need time in there by default date('m/d/Y h:i:s a') will assume current time to be used.